# Rounding up a dataframe consist of string and float both

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe : `df = pd.DataFrame([["abcd", 1.9923], [2.567345454, 5]])`

I want to round it up to 2 decimal places for all the floats. I am using: `df.round(decimals=2)`

However, I am observing that it is working only if the entire dataframe is either `float` or `int`. Presence of any single string in the dataframe is not doing any changes to the entire dataframe. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably need to run a conversion on the column of the DF before rounding it

Comment: just use `df['string column'].astype('float')` and then use `df.round(decimals=2)`....if your string just contain `numeric` value inside it then just change its `type` or just `type cast` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are mixed numeric with strings values is possible use custom lambda function:

```
#first column is filled by strings, so 1. solution not working
df = df.applymap(lambda x: round(x, 2) if isinstance(x, (float, int)) else x)
print (df)
      0     1
0  abcd  1.99
1  2.57  5.00
```

If need convert to numeric and round:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["abcd", 1.9923], ["2.567345454", 5]])

def f(x):
    try:
        return round(float(x), 2)
    except:
        return x

df = df.applymap(f)
print (df)
      0     1
0  abcd  1.99
1  2.57  5.00
```